# KVM public ip setup with subnet /29

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, hetzner

I have a dedicated server from hetzner with one additional /29 subnet

i have configured a bridge network which looks fine to me

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master 
br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1e:67:99:85:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 fe80::21e:67ff:fe99:85cf/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state 
UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1e:67:99:85:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 46.4.73.107/27 brd 46.4.73.127 scope global br0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 188.40.162.113/29 brd 188.40.162.119 scope global br0:1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::21e:67ff:fe99:85cf/64 scope link
```

I installed a guest machine with Ubuntu 18 os and assigned a static ip

```
addresses: 188.40.162.113/29
gateway4: 46.4.73.107
```

But i cant connect vm to public ip

I am using `Kimchi and Wok` as GUI interface for management

Question 1:
 How many public ip do have now as useable 5 or 6?

Question 2:
 How can i bind these public ip with libvirt kvm

Comment: You must configure IP addresses in the VM, not in the host.

Comment: I configured on the VM.. but it doesnt ping or resolve to internet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on networks but

1. I'd think the gateway must be on a reachable network. Your VM is on 188.40.162.113/29 but the gateway is outside the range 188.40.162.113-118.
2. The VM needs a specific IP address from the range 188.40.162.113-118. (112 and 119 are not allowed.)
3. While you can configure your VM host to have 188.40.162.113 and act as a gateway to the VMs, I'd first try without gateway so that you can use 113 for a VM. (I'm not sure whether it is possible to have no gateway.)
4. If you need a gateway for your VMs, you need to set up the host to have an address on the VM network, e.g. 188.40.162.113, and to route between the VM network and the network that gives you internet access. Probably the later network has a gateway 46.4.73.107. If you can connect to your server over the network (rather than the hetzner web-interface) this should be in working order.